# Assign Guid value to C# variable i.e. string

Tags: c#, guid, asp.net-3.5

I am trying to capture GUID value and store in string variable but getting null value

### Model

```
public string StudentRemediationSignatureCheckGuid { get; set; }
```

ContextSession give me GUID value which I like to assign to variable above define

```
_assessmentRemidationObject.StudentRemediationSignatureCheckGuid = ContextSession.GUID.ToString();
```

### update code

```
  public string SeniorAssessorGuid = string.Empty; //global variable


 protected void checkBoxSeniorAssessorSignature_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox SelectedCheckBoxObject4 = (CheckBox)sender;

        if (SelectedCheckBoxObject4.Checked)
        {

            TxtBoxSeniorAssessorSignatureDate.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("d/M/yyyy");

            _assessmentRemidationObject.SeniorAssessorSignatureCheckGuid = ContextSession.GUID.ToString(); 
            SeniorAssessorGuid = ContextSession.GUID.ToString(); 
        }
        else if (!SelectedCheckBoxObject4.Checked)
        {
            TxtBoxSeniorAssessorSignatureDate.Text = string.Empty;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Isn't Your ContextSession is null?

Comment: I think you should use the format paramether. Have you seen this? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/97af8hh4.aspx

Comment: And your question is? Btw. if you *know* you're working with a Guid, then why not store it in the appropriate data type: [Guid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.guid.aspx). Or maybe, `Nullable<Guid>`, i.e. `Guid?`.

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint on that line to see what the exact values are?

Comment: i did and it assign the value but later on when I check it goes to null

Comment: I have found issue..... I am trying to assign value in different method in same class but it shouldn't doing that ...

Comment: Please post the code where the value is gone.

Comment: i have update my question under update code

Answer (score 1):

Do not store the value of the `ContextSession.GUID` in a member of your page `_assessmentRemidationObject` if you loose its value. You need to use a global variable or a persistent storage (a database for example). Try to find where `_assessmentRemidationObject` is resetted before you read it.